# asp.net Mvc4 checkbox issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Code:

```
      <tr>
           <td id="title">Availabilty:</td>
            <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.avaliablity)</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>

        </tr>
```

Error:

```
cannot implicity convert type string to bool
```

Comment: Is `availability` Boolean property?

Answer (score 0):

You can try casting the variable as a bool like so:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => (bool)model.avaliablity)
```

It would also help to see your model to give you a better answer.

Comment: @HarisZia Show us your model please.

Answer (score 0):

Is model.availability a bool?

If not, try to create a public property on your model;

```
public Availability 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        return Boolean.Parse(availability); 
    } 
}
```

In your view, you do:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Avaliablity)
```